# dbExecute with placeholders not working reliably with RSQLite

Tags: r, sqlite, r-dbi

I have a very simple table where I want to update certain rows with `dbExecute()` however the placeholder argument doesn't always work.

```
rows = dbExecute(con, "UPDATE rndid SET assigned = 'N', date = ?
                       WHERE id IN (?)", 
                 params = list(NA, toString(tempIDs$id))
                )
```

The above code works fine if there's only one row in `tempIDs`, but if there's more than one it doesn't update any rows nor does it throw an error.

If I just construct the string with `paste()` instead then it works regardless of the number of rows:

```
rows = dbExecute(con, paste("UPDATE rndid SET assigned = 'N', date = NULL 
                             WHERE id IN (",toString(tempIDs$id),")"
                           )
                 )
```

Anyone with an idea why the placeholder method fails or at least how I can try to debug it? I'd like to see what statement is actually executed by dbExecute.

This is the table def:

```
CREATE TABLE rndid (
  id INTEGER UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  assigned TEXT DEFAULT 'N' NOT NULL,
  date TEXT DEFAULT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is IDs from *params* are getting interpreted as a single string, see below example:

Set up dummy *mtcars* database:

```
library(DBI)

con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
dbWriteTable(con, "mtcars", mtcars[1:5, 1:4])
dbReadTable(con, "mtcars") 
#    mpg cyl disp  hp
# 1 21.0   6  160 110
# 2 21.0   6  160 110
# 3 22.8   4  108  93
# 4 21.4   6  258 110
# 5 18.7   8  360 175

# rows to match on cyl values
x <- c(4,6)
```

Using *sqlInterpolate* without SQL it is becoming `'4, 6'` instead of `4, 6`:

```
sqlInterpolate(ANSI(),
               "UPDATE mtcars SET mpg = 0, disp = ?x1 WHERE cyl IN (?x2)",
               x1 = NA, x2 = toString(x))
# <SQL> UPDATE mtcars SET mpg = 0, disp = NULL WHERE cyl IN ('4, 6')
```

We need to use *SQL* to avoid:

```
dbExecute(con,
          sqlInterpolate(ANSI(),
                         "UPDATE mtcars SET mpg = 0, disp = ?x1 WHERE cyl IN (?x2)",
                         x1 = NA, x2 = SQL(toString(x))))
# [4]

dbReadTable(con, "mtcars") 
#    mpg cyl disp  hp
# 1  0.0   6   NA 110
# 2  0.0   6   NA 110
# 3  0.0   4   NA  93
# 4  0.0   6   NA 110
# 5 18.7   8  360 175

#disconnect
dbDisconnect(con)
```

Comment: That's very clear and now I know about sqlInterpolate(). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While I think zx8754's answer describes an intended use of `sqlInterpolate`, the fact that you start with bound parameters (`?`) and then switch away from the protections and efficiencies that they can provide is unfortunate.

An alternative is to expand the `IN (?)` to be correct. In reality, what you need in this example is `IN (?,?)`. Instead of interpolating the string with data (something that might be discouraged, at least in theory), interpolate the string with parameters (question marks); not only does this provides protection against inadvertent SQL injection (it is not always malicious, it can happen with encoding problems), it also allows for repeated queries using a stored-result query (for multiple bindings, if you use it) and better query optimization in the DBMS. (For the latter: some DBMSes will optimize the query and then re-use the optimized query if it is unchanged; unfortunately, often (most? always? idk) just changing these parameters `'4','6'` negates that re-use.)

Using the same premise as zx8754's answer:

```r
library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
dbWriteTable(con, "mtcars", mtcars[1:5, 1:4])
dbReadTable(con, "mtcars")
#    mpg cyl disp  hp
# 1 21.0   6  160 110
# 2 21.0   6  160 110
# 3 22.8   4  108  93
# 4 21.4   6  258 110
# 5 18.7   8  360 175
qry <- sprintf("UPDATE mtcars SET mpg = 0, disp = ? WHERE cyl IN (%s)",
               paste(rep("?", length(x)), collapse = ","))
qry
# [1] "UPDATE mtcars SET mpg = 0, disp = ? WHERE cyl IN (?,?)"
dbExecute(con, qry, params = c(NA, x))
# [1] 4
dbReadTable(con, "mtcars")
#    mpg cyl disp  hp
# 1  0.0   6   NA 110
# 2  0.0   6   NA 110
# 3  0.0   4   NA  93
# 4  0.0   6   NA 110
# 5 18.7   8  360 175
```

I'm not saying that `sqlInterpolate` is unsafe; on the contrary, it is meant to be a safer way (than `sprintf`/`paste`/etc) that preempts the likelihood of inadvertent sql injection; however, it defeats the intent of keeping queries free of data (which is needed to maximize the benefit/effect of query optimization).